# stopping scrolling back-to-top button above the footer at all times pure css and html

Tags: html, css, button, footer

I've got the button to float down the page as the user scroll's down the page, but is there a way to make it that after scrolling all the way to the bottom that it stays above the footer at all times.

I've tried to z-index, but all the solution I've found use javascript/jquery, I need it to be pure html and css

edited: the footer code is located under the button code in the html, also how do you make sure that regardless of the size of the page, the footer stays stays stuck to the bottom.

```css
.footer {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #1B1B1B;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: lighter;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  border-top-width: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  position: static;
  font-weight: 200;
  bottom: 10px;
}


/*Floating Back-To-Top Button*/

#myBtn {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  float: right;
  right: 18.5%;
  left: 77.25%;
  max-width: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-color: rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.2);
  background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
  padding: .5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  z-index: 1000;
}


/*On Hover Color Change*/

#myBtn:hover {
  background-color: #7dbbf1;
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn"><a href="#top">Top</a></button>

<div class="footer">

<p><span>Aditya's Website | Websystems Assignment | Copyright &copy; 2019</span></p>
 <a href="index.html"> Home </a> | <a href="past.html">Past</a> | <a href="future.html">Future</a> | <a href="comments.html">Comments</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why you used position: static;? If you want footer at the bottom and fixed then use  position: fixed;

Comment: I changed it from static to fixed but the footer still doesn't stay stuck to the bottom edit: never mind it worked, i had the padding on the bottom which was making it fail.

Comment: how do I make it so that the footer doesn't cover the bottom of the content from the body. Do I need to add padding somewhere in the footer or the body?

Comment: Can you share your current output and expected output? If you use fixed then footer will always be fixed at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

`button` is coming on top of `footer`. please check the code.. Or add the `footer` `HTML` and `CSS` in the Question

```css
.footer {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: lighter;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  border-top-width: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 200;
  bottom: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}


/*Floating Back-To-Top Button*/

#myBtn {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  float: right;
  right: 18.5%;
  left: 77.25%;
  max-width: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-color: rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.2);
  background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
  padding: .5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  z-index: 1000;
}


/*On Hover Color Change*/

#myBtn:hover {
  background-color: #7dbbf1;
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn"><a href="#top">Top</a></button>
<footer class="footer">
</footer>
```